# Running Mercurial on a Flash Drive?

Tags: mercurial, portability, usb-flash-drive

So I do a lot of work on a school computer. We can't install anything but we have most of our tools on our flash drives but I was wondering if there's a way to get Command Prompt to use Mercurial off of my Flash Drive. Let's say in theory that Mercurial's files were on my flash drive, where would I go from there?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Say your flash drive was drive G: and your Mercurial executables are in G:\mercurial

Open a command prompt and enter:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;G:\mercurial
```

Proceed to use `hg` as normal

This should work, in theory. If you're on a *nix computer, you would do something like this (given /media/FLASHDRIVE is the path to your flash drive):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/media/FLASHDRIVE/mercurial
```

Hope that helps!

*EDIT*

In response to the comment below:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Mercurial enabler :)
set PATH=%PATH%;G:\mercurial
cmd.exe
```

Should do it :)

Comment: That worked! Thanks but got another question! Is there any way to incorporate that into a .bat file so I'd just open that and have it open command prompt and run that at the same time?

Comment: You sir, are an instant winrar. Thank you and I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 26):

To make Bryan's solution "truly" portable in Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7, assuming the BAT file is inside Mercurial's directory, use:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0%
```

So, no more hardcoded paths.

Comment: Ya, we noticed the previous code was kind of un-portable but we fixed it. The code here looks different from ours though, what exactly does %~dp0% do/stand for?

Comment: The above's pretty good, actually. That crazy %~dp0% basically evaluates to the path of the currently running bat file

Answer (score 23):

download the tortoise hg .msi setup

```
msiexec /a tortoisehg-1.1.4-hg-1.6.4-x64.msi /qb TARGETDIR=f:\hg-temp
```

it will extract the tortise hg files to f:\hg-temp path,

```
goto f:\hg-temp\PFiles\TortoiseHg and copy it to F:\hg
```

Delete f:\hg-temp\PFiles\TortoiseHg

Then add f:\hg to your path

```
set PATH=%PATH%;f:\hg
```

(f:\ is your flash drive)

Comment: I still use this method to produce a portable tortoisehg. One thing I would add is that if you don't have administrative rights, you can "advertise" the product to yourself, allowing you to unpack it. Just run `msiexec /ju tortoisehg-(version).msi` prior to the above.